# Query Join Condition

Tags: sql, t-sql

I Have two tables named account and assignedgroup. In account table there are two columns named ID and sourceaccount and In assignedgroup I have two columns named ID and assignedgroup.

I want to select ID by joining account and assignedgroup tables. I did something like this:

```
select a.ID
from account a 
  left outer join assignedgroup b 
   on a.sourceaccount = b.assignedgorup
```

But I get Null as output the reason being that The values in sourceaccount are like this

sourceaccount:

```
sample
sample
```

and whereas the values in assignedgroup are like this

assignedgroup:

```
sample-L1
sample-P-L1
```

Can anyone help me on how to join these two tables?

I want to get all the ID's whenever there is a sample value in both sourceaccount and assignedgroup.

It is comparing sample with sample-L1 since those are not equal it is returning null but I want the ID even if it has values like that. I mean if somepart of the column values matches then also I want those values to be displayed

Comment: you cannot join tables that don't share a common key...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.id
FROM    account a
LEFT JOIN
        assignedgroup b
ON      b.assignedgorup LIKE a.sourceaccount + '-%'
```

Comment: Even though the DB design must be nasty, if you need a solution I reckon this is it.

Comment: The problem with this solution is it won't work if you happen to have two values that are different accounts but have simliar names such as Sam and Sample. They would both join to the same records.

Comment: Thank you so much Quassnoi. It worked for me. I know the DB design is nasty but I have been given to do this.

Comment: @Sam: see the post update per @HLGEM's comment. This will work unless the character `-` is allowed in account names (in which case you should define the separator more clearly)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly your database structure is flawed.  If you need the first part of the assigned group to join to the  source account, it should be stored that way in a separate column. YOu can do some manipulation to get the right values, but changing the datbase structure is the best fix as any data manipulation you do in a join is very expensive (and likely to introduce bugs).

Answer (score 0):

Since the actual data within those two tables does not actually match, you cannot join those rows in those tables unless you start making some rather broad assumptions about the nature of the data in those tables. For example, this might work:

```
SELECT a.ID
 from Account a
  left outer join AssignedGroup b
   on a.sourceaccount = left(b.assignedgroup, 6)
```

or, more generically,

```
SELECT a.ID
 from Account a
  left outer join AssignedGroup b
   on a.sourceaccount = left(b.assignedgroup, len(a.sourceaccount))
```

However, this is truly horrible code, logic, and database design, and I would only use this while tyring to troubleshoot and/or fix messed-up data.

Comment: @Quassnoi's LIKE clause would work as well, but it's still a broad assumption and poor design.

Comment: I once took a server down joining a to b, substringing b based on a's length.... (plus some other equally daft logic)